# Error replacing '+' , '-' , '*' , '/'

Tags: java

What do I have to put for replace "+"?

```
if (msg.contains("+")){
        msg.replace("+", "###%SUM%###");
}
```

Answer (score 4):

String is immutable in Java:

```
msg = msg.replace("+", "###%SUM%###");
```

`replace()` does not modify `msg`, but instead returning a new String object.

Comment: You're too late to the party. ;-)

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young I blame my Internet connection ;)

Answer (score 2):

Use this:

```
msg = msg.replace("+", "###%SUM%###");
```

Calling `msg.replace` doesn't alter the string itself. You actually have to store the result somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
msg=msg.replace("+","###%SUM%###");
```

and no need of contains

Hope this helps